# cached notwork image is working fine in debug mode but showing place holder in release mode flutter ,any solution please?

Tags: android, image, flutter, caching, networking

```
 CachedNetworkImage(
                                      imageUrl:
                                          snapshot.data[index].cat_image,
                                      imageBuilder:
                                          (context, imageProvider) =>
                                              Container(
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          image: DecorationImage(
                                            image: imageProvider,
                                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      placeholder: (context, url) => Center(
                                          child:
                                              CircularProgressIndicator()),
                                      errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                          Center(child: Icon(Icons.error)),
                                    ),
```

i am getting image link from server in future builder and cached notwork image is working fine in debug mode but showing place holder in release mode

Comment: either make sure you image url has "https", or make your app available for insecure connections.

Answer (score 0):

It's a issue that your app can't access internet.
Go to Android>app>src>main>AndroidManifest.xml and add this line in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

It'll solve the issue. Thanks

If it doesn't work. Try this.

Add this to your android/app/build.gradle file:

```
android {
   ...

    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version of cached_network_image 2.5.1?

Comment: It should've worked. Anyway, try this version of cached_network_image:
cached_network_image: ^2.5.0

Comment: android {
   ...

    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}   , This one